# Difference between isotherms and isotheres

Tags: temperature

I encounter both similar terms while reading, isotherms and isotheres. Could someone help distinguish and explain to me the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The general term *isotherm* refers to a [line of equal or constant temperature](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Isotherm), while *isothere* refers more specifically to [lines of constant average summer temperature](https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1256/wea.33.06).**

For what it's worth, coming from a background in forecasting and research centered around active weather rather than longer-term climate, *isotherm* is an extremely commonly-used term in weather discussions but I can't recall ever seeing *isothere* used in practice before now.